# Python kernel crash in Jupyter notebook when calling fig.add_axes()

Tags: python, matplotlib, crash, jupyter-notebook

So I have Anaconda on Windows running an environment with a bunch of stuff and:

- **Python 3.6.6**
- **matplotlib 2.2.3**

And when I run following code, my Python kernel crashes:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
fig.add_axes([10,200,50,50])
```

Does anyone know why that happens or perhaps can try to reproduce so that I can know it's not just my pc dying on me?

Comment: The list you pass to `add_axes` are fractions of the figure height and width and so should be between 0 and 1. That could be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: Use reasonable coordinates to place your axes, i.e. numbers between 0 and 1, for example

```
fig.add_axes([0.1 ,0.2, 0.5, 0.5])
```

I suppose the numbers are just too big. The figure ranges between 0 and 1. So while there are certainly cases where you may want to add an axes outside that range e.g. `[-0.1,0.7,0.3,0.5]`, creating an axes at a coordinate 200 times the figure height is not very useful.

Well, "not useful" does not mean it should crash. So what's probably happening is that you are trying to *show* this figure on screen in a version which expands the figure size to the figure content. This might happen by default in a jupyter notebook, which shows the figure that is saved via `fig.savefig(..., bbox_inches="tight")`. So assuming a figure size of 10 by 10 inch, `[10,200,50,50]` leads to a figure tried to be saved of dimension 60*10=600 inch in width and 250*10=2500 inch in height. With a dpi of 72, this leads to a png image of (43200 x 180000) pixels. This seems to be to much to be handled by the renderer.

When running the code as script (adding `fig.savefig(..., bbox_inches="tight")`) you actually do get an error using the usual `Agg`-based renderer,

```
RuntimeError: Unknown exception in RendererAgg
```

which means that the renderer is not capable of producing the figure. I'm not sure why in Ipython/Juypter no such error is raised.

A more useful errormessage is shown with the "cairo" renderer,

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("Qt4Cairo")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
fig.add_axes([10,200,50,50])
fig.savefig("hugeaxesposition.png", bbox_inches="tight")
```

shows

```
cairocffi.CairoError: cairo returned CAIRO_STATUS_INVALID_SIZE: 
    invalid value (typically too big) for the size of the input (surface, pattern, etc.)
```

I would agree that seeing such error would be more useful from a user's perspective than a crash.

While the reason for no error being shown in IPython/Jupyter might be interesting to investigate further, it sure has no high priority, since matplotlib is not designed to produce huge figures anyways.

Comment: 2500 inches? That's a lotta scrolling. =)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the documentation of [Figure.add_axes](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.add_axes), the first argument is:

> rect : sequence of float
>
> The dimensions [left, bottom, width, height]
> of the new axes. All quantities are in fractions of figure width and
> height.

The values are fractions of the figure height and width and so should be between 0 and 1